# how to connect to mysql server in another system from ubuntu

Tags: android, mysql

I am using ubuntu, and am programming in android. So in my application i need to connect to mysql database which is in another system. When i searched, i foud that wamp server is need, wanp only works in windows rigth? So what can i do? please help

Comment: No, a WAMP server is not needed, just a MySQL server, which will run under Linux as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way dont u tray xampp server its and alternetive for wamp its a cross paltform also available for linux. U may download from here:- http://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: is there any blog where i can see the codes and steps for implementing it in my application?

Answer (score 1):

WAMP is an acronym that stands for Windows Apache MySQL PHP. It is also often referred to as web-stack because the each part "stacks" on top of the previous one to create a complete system. The linux equivalent is a LAMP stack (yes, you guessed right! it stands for Linux Apache MySQL PHP).

A good practice is to install the stack on a virtual machine (if your system has enough resources) to keep things clean and separate. Google for "LAMP" and you'll find quite a few alternatives (from bitnami and turnkey to name a few). Of course there is nothing stopping you from installing directly on your active OS.

Once you have a web stack installed, you will also need the client development libraries for mysql which are available through Ubuntu repositories. These have to be installed on your development machine in order to be available to your build tools.

Comment: is there any blog where i can see the codes and steps for implementing it in my application?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: as in my query, i am doing app development in android

Comment: Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/sql/DataSource.html)